# jQuery add input fields and handle select change event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to clone a row with 1 input or select and 1 select field.
Depends on the value of the first select it should change the second to an input or a select fields. It works for the parent but not for the clones.

```
    jQuery("body").delegate("p", "click", function(){
        var $tr    = jQuery(this).closest('.tr_clone');
        var $clone = $tr.clone();
        $tr.after($clone);
    });
    jQuery('.art_der_fahrt').hide();
    jQuery('.wert_input').show();
    jQuery(".fahrtenbuch_aenderungen").change(function() {
                if(jQuery(this).val() == '52') {
                    jQuery(this).parent('td').next('td').children(".art_der_fahrt").show();
                    jQuery(this).parent('td').next('td').children('.wert_input').hide();
                }
                else {
                    jQuery(this).parent('td').next('td').children(".art_der_fahrt").hide();
                    jQuery(this).parent('td').next('td').children('.wert_input').show();
                }

            });

<td>
    <select class="fahrtenbuch_aenderungen" name="fahrtenbuch_aenderungen">
      <option></option>
      <option value="24">Fahrtziel</option>
      <option value="23">Besuchte Personen / Firmen / Objekte</option>
      <option value="3">Fahrer</option>
      <option value="52">Art der Fahrt</option>
      <option value="14">Fahrzeugstandort</option>
      <option value="111">Fahrtzweck</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input value="" class="wert_input" name="wert" type="text">
    <span class="art_der_fahrt">
        <select tabindex="111" class="test" name="select">
            <option></option>
            <option value="Dienstfahrt">Dienstfahrt</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="Wohnung">Wohnung</option>
            <option value="Bereitschaft">Bereitschaft</option>
            <option value="3">Fahrer</option>
            <option value="52">Privatfahrt</option>
            <option value="Familienheimfahrt">Familienheimfahrt</option>
        </select>
    </span>

</td>
<td colspan="2">
<p>Click me!</p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding the change listener –

```
jQuery(".fahrtenbuch_aenderungen").change(function() {
```

– at a time when there is only one `select` element. Only that element will have the listener. You need to use delegates here as well:

```
jQuery("body").delegate(".fahrtenbuch_aenderungen", "change", function() {
```

Using `.delegate` here, in the sense that you've used it in your own post, assuming an older version of jQuery. As others have pointed out, you should prefer `.on` if it's available.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XzkA6/)

Answer (score 2):

use `.on`

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "p", function(){
```

also

```
jQuery(".fahrtenbuch_aenderungen").on('change',(function() {
```

because .on already replaces `.live` and `.bind` and `.delegate`.
and .on is also faster than other..http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-live-vs-delegate-vs-on/5

Comment: This should be a comment as it does not address the issue. `delegate` may be slower but it *works*, so changing to `on` won't solve anything here.

Comment: This should really now be the accepted answer. Delegate() is still a valid way of doing things, but its a low-level interface. The on() method is intended to be the "normal" high-level interface.

Answer (score -1):

Use following

```
$("td > p").on("click", function(){
    // your code here
});
```

"on" can bind events to dynamically generated dom

Comment: Yes it can, but not using the code you've posted. The event listener will only be bound to existing `p` tags in your code. See Parmar's answer for an example on how to use delegated events with `on`.